# How can I add more attributes to links with this working code?

Tags: php

This code works, but I need help making a few adjustments, please.  Currently, the code adds this link attribute: rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" data-analytics="Link-1" to all links in my WordPress content that have this URL: /go/link-1.  I need to do the same thing with a lot more links and have them add different link attributes for each link.

For instance, I also need: /go/link-2 to have the link attributes: rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" data-analytics="Link-2" and so on.

How can I do this? I'm a complete novice so any help is truly appreciated!  Thank you.

```
function rewrite_links($content) {
  $content = preg_replace_callback(
  '/<a[^>]*href=["|\']([^"|\']*)["|\'][^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>/i',
    function($m) {
        $LINK_URLS = explode(",","/go/link-1");
        $i = 0;
        $j = count($LINK_URLS);
        while ($i < $j) { ;
            if ((strpos(strtolower($m[1]), strtolower($LINK_URLS[$i])) !== false)) {
                $match = "yes";             
            }
            $i++;
        }
        if ($match == "yes") {
            return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" data-analytics="Link-1">'.$m[2].'</a>';
        } else {
            if ((strpos(strtolower($m[1]), $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) !== false) || (substr($m[1],0,1) == "#")) {
              return $m[0];
            } else {
              return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" rel="follow noopener" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
            }
        }
    },
$content);

  return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'rewrite_links', 100);
```

Comment: Put the attributes you want to add in an array. Then you can use `implode(' ', $attrs)` to get them as a combined string to put in the links.

Comment: And if you need different sets of attributes for different URLs - then use a multidimensional array, and use the URL/slug as key on the top level.

Comment: `$LINK_URLS = explode(",","/go/link-1");` - exploding the value `/go/link-1` at a comma - which it contains exactly _zero_ of in the first place - is a bit pointless.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, could you please show me how and where to implement this array? Appreciate the help a lot.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you.  Are you suggesting I remove part of that code?  If so could you please tell me which part?  `$LINK_URLS = explode(",","/go/link-1");`

Comment: Was this an attempt to use this for multiple URLs, passed as a comma-separated string? Okay, then it makes sense, but why not use an array to begin with instead, `$LINK_URLS = ["/go/link-1", "..."];`

Comment: @CBroe Yes, it was for multiple URLs originally. To be completely honest I have no idea what I'm doing.  This code is from a blog I follow and I'm trying to adapt it for use on my local food pantry site.  Thank you.